# How to average two variables in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am attending CoderCamps and I am in week 2. My final project is to create a web app using HTML and Javascript that allows the user to type a passage inside of a textarea and then display the average words per sentence, the number of words, spaces and sentences on the web page.

I have everything working properly except I can't seem to get the average to sum up... Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Here's my code so far.

```
var button = document.getElementById("button");
var text = document.getElementById("textarea");
var totalSpaces = 0;
var totalWords = 0;
var avgWords = 0;
var totalSentences = 0;


button.addEventListener("click", function(){
    var text = document.getElementById("textarea").value;
    text.length

    for (var i =0; i<text.length; i++){
        if(text[i] == " "){
            totalSpaces++;
        }
        if(text[i] == "."){
            totalSentences++;
        }
        if(text[i] == "?"){
            totalSentences++;
        }
        if(text[i] == "!"){
            totalSentences++;
        }

    }



    document.getElementById("avg").innerHTML = totalWords / totalSentences;
    document.getElementById("words").innerHTML = totalWords = totalSpaces +1;
    document.getElementById("sentences").innerHTML = totalSentences;
    document.getElementById("spaces").innerHTML = totalSpaces;

    totalSpaces = 0;
    totalWords = 0;
    avgWords = 0;
    totalSentences = 0;
});
```

Comment: You're reading the value of totalWords before setting it to `totalSpaces + 1`.

Comment: you calculate the average before assigning a value to `totalWords`, its 0 at the time

Comment: Do you suggest I create a separate function to calculate it?

Comment: If this is the whole code then no, just move the calculation before you set the HTML values.

Comment: That is my full javascript code. It's assuming I don't know what will be inputed in the textarea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var button = document.getElementById("button");
var text = document.getElementById("textarea");
var totalSpaces = 0;
var totalWords = 0;
var avgWords = 0;
var totalSentences = 0;


button.addEventListener("click", function(){
  var text = document.getElementById("textarea").value;


  for (var i =0; i<text.length; i++){
      if(text[i] == " "){
          totalSpaces++;
      }
      if(text[i] == "."){
          totalSentences++;
      }
      if(text[i] == "?"){
          totalSentences++;
      }
      if(text[i] == "!"){
          totalSentences++;
      }

  }
  totalWords = totalSpaces;


  document.getElementById("avg").innerHTML = totalWords / totalSentences;
  document.getElementById("words").innerHTML = totalWords;
  document.getElementById("sentences").innerHTML = totalSentences;
  document.getElementById("spaces").innerHTML = totalSpaces;

  totalSpaces = 0;
  totalWords = 0;
  avgWords = 0;
  totalSentences = 0;
});
```

Comment: How I calculated the total of words was I was took each space and added 1. What I'm trying to do now is take the total words and total sentences and divide them to get an average of words per sentence. also I'm not allowed to use .split(). I shouldve mentioned that

Comment: then just assign the totalSpaces to totalWords, as Above.

Comment: and that worked lol, wow... well Thank you! I'm too much of a noob yet lol, but still having fun being frustrated lol.

Comment: np, im glad to be helpful

Comment: @TylerMoyer please accept mine as the answer if you don't mind. Thanks

Comment: @tima sorry I don't get you. do you mean there is a possibility that spaces could in the beginning of the string?

Comment: @tima I didnt address this issue cuz the guy rasing the question coded in this way, it is very hard coded, i dont recomand it either.